# How to use built-in function pop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, iteration

I am confused about a really simple problem with list built-in function, pop.

The code is simple as it can be.

```
L=[1,2]
for i in L:
    print i
    L.pop(0)
```

and it gives

```
1
```

I tried it with a longer list

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in L:
    print i
    L.pop(0)
```

and it gave me

```
1
3
5
```

So, back to the first code, what I thought was from the line 'for i in L', the for loop will run for '1' first, so it will print i and then L.pop(0) will remove '1' from L. Then, there will be another loop for '2 in L', which will print 2, making L empty list. However, it only returned 1, and 1,3,5 in case of second case.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You are missing some basic concepts of `for` loop here.

You are popping from the start of the list by using `pop(0)`. So after popping, all elements shift one position left and hence changing the indexes of every remaining element. In this case `for` loop's `next()` method `yield`s newly shifted element for the current index it holds. Hence you see such behaviour.

If you change your code by adding some `print` statement, it will become more clear.

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in L:
    print L, i
    L.pop(0)

# Output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 1 # It has index 0 here
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 3 # It has index 1 here
[3, 4, 5, 6] 5 # It has index 2 here
# 6 is not printed here  as it has index 3 to print here but our L is reduced to [4, 5, 6] which does not contain any index 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L=[1,2]
for i in L:
   print i
   L.pop(0)
```

In this example you will get output as 1 because foreach loop runs only one time. In the first iteration where i=0, L[i] equals to 1 and print it. When you pop down one item from the list length of the list is to be 1. So foreach loop will automatically break after L.pop(0)  statement

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in L:
   print i
   L.pop(0)
```

In this code, consider the first iteration where i=0. It will print the 1. Then by pop the first element from the list length of the list will be 5. Now list is auto adjust as [2,3,4,5,6]. By considering next iteration when i is equal to 1, it will print 3 where L[1]=3. After that popping the first element of list causing L=[3,4,5,6]. Finally print 5 as L[2].